# How to get Jira time?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

In Jira, You can select time (timezone) different from server time. How to get this time (or timezone) during development?

Answer (score 0):

```
 timezone = Objects.firstNonNull(
          TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry().getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()),
            TimeZone.getDefault()
    );
```

Comment: what is TimeZoneRegistryFactory ? Is it possible to do with JIRA API?